# passing variable to external js file -laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, charts

I'm using Laravel and I want to pass variable to external js file
here is controller code :

```
 public function reports()
  {         

   $phone = Product::where('type','phone')->where('year','2018')->get(); 
                     $phoneCount =count($phone);
   $laptop = Product::where('type','laptop')->where('year','2018')->get(); 
                     $laptopCount =count($laptop);

  }

        return view('report', ['phone' => $phoneCount,'laptop'=>$laptopCount ]);
```

and here is external chart.js code but its not work

```
data: {
      labels: ["phone","laptop"],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Processes Completed",
          backgroundColor: "rgb(76, 132, 255)",
          borderColor: "rgba(76, 132, 255,0)",
          data:[{{$phoneCount}},{{$laptopCount}}] ,
          pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(76, 132, 255,0)",
          pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(76, 132, 255,1)",
          pointHoverRadius: 3,
          pointHitRadius: 30
        },]
    },
```

Can any one help me please

Answer (score 3):

You can't pass a PHP variable to a `.js` file directly. But you can pass it to view, where you use  the src of `chart.js`, then you can use the variable with `chart.js`. Like this example :

**report.blade.php**

```html
// make sure you define this variable before load chart.js
<script>
   var phoneCount = {{ phoneCount }};
   var laptopCount = {{ laptopCount }};
</script>
```

**chart.js**

```js
data: {
      labels: ["phone","laptop"],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Processes Completed",
          backgroundColor: "rgb(76, 132, 255)",
          borderColor: "rgba(76, 132, 255,0)",
          data:[phoneCount, laptopCount] ,
          pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(76, 132, 255,0)",
          pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(76, 132, 255,1)",
          pointHoverRadius: 3,
          pointHitRadius: 30
        },]
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

I refactored your code.

**// 1. Controller**

```
public function reports()
  {         

   $phone = Product::where('type','phone')->where('year','2018')->get(); 
                     $phoneCount =count($phone);
   $laptop = Product::where('type','laptop')->where('year','2018')->get(); 
                     $laptopCount =count($laptop);

   $jsonResult = json_encode([$phoneCount, $laptopCount]);

    return view('report', compact('jsonResult'));

  }
```

**2. In view, a line before you import chart.js file,**

```
<script> window.count = '<?php echo $jsonResult ?>'; </script>
```

**3. In chart.js file**

```
var myResult = JSON.parse(window.count);

data: {
      labels: ["phone","laptop"],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Processes Completed",
          backgroundColor: "rgb(76, 132, 255)",
          borderColor: "rgba(76, 132, 255,0)",
          data:[myResult[0], myResult[1]] ,
          pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(76, 132, 255,0)",
          pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(76, 132, 255,1)",
          pointHoverRadius: 3,
          pointHitRadius: 30
        },]
    },
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

Can you access or var_dump the variables "phone" and "laptop" on the view? If not, first make sure they passed proper form the controller.

Try

```
@php var_dump($phone, $laptop); @endphp
```

or via Blade syntax @Droid mentions:

```
{{ $phone }}
{{ $laptop }}
```